# nested li value on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have elements which have nested li elements and i made a click function to get the value. Every time i click i am getting the same value again and again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.cat-select').on('click',function(){
        $('.cat-list').css('display','block');
         $('.sub-list').css('display','block');

    });

    $(document).on('click','.cat-list>li',function(){
        var selectedVal = $(this).clone()   //clone the element
            .children() //select all the children
            .remove()   //remove all the children
            .end()  //again go back to selected element
            .text();    //get the text of elemen
        console.log(selectedVal);
        $('.cat-select').text(selectedVal);
    });
</script>


<div class="form-group">
   <label for="input-placeholder" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
        <style type="text/css">
            .cat-list, .sub-list{ display: none; }
        </style>
        <div class="cat-group">
            <button class="cat-select" type="button">Select Category</button>
            <ul class="cat-list">
                <li class="have-child">Electronics 
                    <ul class="sub-list">
                        <li class="have-child"> Mobiles & Tablets
                            <ul class="sub-list">
                                <li>Mobiles</li>
                                <li>Tablets</li>
                                <li class="have-child">Accessories</li>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Power Bank</li>
                                        <li>Phone Cases</li>
                                    </ul>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="have-child">Cameras
                            <ul class="sub-list">
                                <li>DSLRs</li>
                                <li>Drones</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>        
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every time i click i am getting the same value

https://jsfiddle.net/yx4Ldt80/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you see is because you only attach the event handler to the child of the `.cat-list` through your use of the `>` operator.

To solve this, remove that from the selector and call `stopPropagation()` on the event to stop it bubbling up the DOM. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cat-list li', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var selectedVal = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
    $('.cat-select').text(selectedVal);
})
```

```js
$('.cat-select').on('click', function() {
  $('.cat-list, .sub-list').toggle();
});

$(document).on('click', '.cat-list li', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var selectedVal = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
  $('.cat-select').text(selectedVal);
})
```

```css
.cat-list,
.sub-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="input-placeholder" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>

  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="cat-group">
      <button class="cat-select" type="button">Select Category</button>

      <ul class="cat-list">
        <li class="have-child">Electronics
          <ul class="sub-list">
            <li class="have-child">
              Mobiles &amp; Tablets
              <ul class="sub-list">
                <li>Mobiles</li>
                <li>Tablets</li>
                <li class="have-child">Accessories
                  <ul>
                    <li>Power Bank</li>
                    <li>Phone Cases</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="have-child">
              Cameras
              <ul class="sub-list">
                <li>DSLRs</li>
                <li>Drones</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that I fixed the HTML in your 'Accessories' `ul` as it was outside of the parent `li`.

Answer (score 1):

## "*Never use*" `Event.stopPropagation()`

The worst thing you can do (as suggested by answers here and around the web) is to use `Event.stopPropagation()`.
Don't use `Event.stopPropagation()`, well, unless you **really know what you're doing**.

An Application should be **always *aware* of every event** happening in it's context.
Imagine you build a popup, modal, or a custom select-box that needs to close if you click anywhere else in the page. Well, congratulations, a LI element just stopped you from doing so.

## Use `Event.target` instead

```
function myClickHandler(ev) {
  if (ev.target !== this) return; // Ignore if non-this called the event
  console.log( this.textContent );
}
```

Here's an example with your specific use-case:

```js
const $cat = $('.cat-select');

$cat.on('click', function() {
  $('.cat-list, .sub-list').toggle();
});

$(document).on('click', '.cat-list li', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target !== this) return; // Ignore if non-this called the event
  const value = $(this).contents().filter((i, el) => el.nodeType == 3)[0].nodeValue;
  $cat.text(value);
});


// Than, 3000 lines later... THANK YOU BECAUSE:
$('body').on('click', function() {
  // Close a popup or something 
  console.clear(); console.log(`YEY I registered an event!
  Thank you for not using Event.preventDefault()`);
});
```

```css
.cat-list, 
.sub-list  {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="input-placeholder" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="cat-group">
      <button class="cat-select" type="button">Select Category</button>
      <ul class="cat-list">
        <li class="have-child">Electronics
          <ul class="sub-list">
            <li class="have-child"> Mobiles & Tablets
              <ul class="sub-list">
                <li>Mobiles</li>
                <li>Tablets</li>
                <li class="have-child">Accessories</li>
                <ul>
                  <li>Power Bank</li>
                  <li>Phone Cases</li>
                </ul>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="have-child">Cameras
              <ul class="sub-list">
                <li>DSLRs</li>
                <li>Drones</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the clicked element based the [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property. Although you can avoid the clone by [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents) and [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter) methods which help to filter out text nodes.

```
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(e) {
  // if target element is not `li` tag then get closest li tag
  var selectedVal = (e.target.nodeType == 'LI' ? $(e.target) : $(e.target).closest('li'))
    .contents() // get all children nodes 
    .filter(function() { // filter  out text nodes
      return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).text(); // get text content

  $('.cat-select').text(selectedVal);
})
```

```js
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(e) {
  // if target element is not `li` tag then get closest li tag
  var selectedVal = (e.target.nodeType == 'LI' ? $(e.target) : $(e.target).closest('li'))
    .contents() // get all children nodes 
    .filter(function() { // filter  out text nodes
      return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).text(); // get text content

  $('.cat-select').text(selectedVal);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="input-placeholder" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>

  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="cat-group">
      <button class="cat-select" type="button">
        Select Category</button>

      <ul class="cat-list">
        <li class="have-child">Electronics
          <ul class="sub-list">
            <li class="have-child">Mobiles & Tablets
              <ul class="sub-list">
                <li>Mobiles</li>
                <li>Tablets</li>
                <li class="have-child">Accessories</li>
                <ul>
                  <li>Power Bank</li>
                  <li>Phone Cases</li>
                </ul>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="have-child">Cameras
              <ul class="sub-list">
                <li>DSLRs</li>
                <li>Drones</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You've got a few typos here, and it doesn't stop the `Electronics` value always being set as the event bubbles up

Answer (score -1):

i hope this one is helping u

```
$('.cat-select').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
    $('.cat-list').css('display', 'block');
    $('.sub-list').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
$(document).on('click', function() {
    $(this).each('.cat-list li', function() {
      var selectedVal = $(this).clone() //clone the element
        .children() //select all the children
        .remove() //remove all the children
        .end() //again go back to selected element
        .text(); //get the text of elemen
        console.log(selectedVal);
        $('.cat-select').text(selectedVal);
    });
});
```